# Read Time Out Exception

Tags: apex, rest-api, callout, exception

I am calling REST API method to update some data to another system from apex but getting "common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: Read timed out" exception.

Here is my request code

```
HttpRequest httpReq2 = new HttpRequest();
httpReq2.setEndpoint(endPoint + '/BoothSales/Customers?Id=' + '12345' + '&companyName=' + 'TestCompany'+ '&phone='+ '65465464');           
httpReq2.setMethod('PUT'); 
httpReq2.setHeader('Content-Length', '1024');
//httpReq2.setTimeout(60000);
httpReq2.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
httpReq.setHeader('Content-Type', 'x-urlformencoded;application/json;charset=UTF-8');

Http http = new Http();      
HttpResponse httpRes2 = http.send(httpReq2);
System.debug('#####httpRes2: ' + httpRes2);
```

I tried the same request using Postman and it takes about 400ms and got a successful response. Please help me to find the problem in the above code.

Comment: Have you checked this out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43553643/common-apex-runtime-impl-executionexception-unexpected-end-of-file-from-server

Comment: You have to ask the 3rd party to whitelist the below set of Salesforce IP ranges
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003652&type=1

Comment: @Pranay So how Postman get a successful response?

Comment: Its possible that 3rd party has whitlisted your local IP's

Comment: @Pranay, sorry but not yet...

Comment: @MohitKumar May be you (postman) are in the same network where the webservice is hosted or your network is already whitelisted. Try to test it from your home network or other network.

Comment: @Saroj, service is also on the different system.

Comment: I have made 2 calls in this code, first call to get token and getting a successful response with token and then doing above call...is there any issue with this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the body is not present we can specify the length as 0.

```
httpReq2.setHeader('Content-Length', '0');
```

Now, I got a successful response.